# Graph Visualization on android

Tags: java, android, graph, information-visualization

I have been looking around for a visualization framework that would aid graph visualization on Android. I have found a wealth of charting frameworks, but none that would allow graph visualization and manipulate like the JavaScript Infovis toolkit. I am looking for a native library, because the JavaScript libraries are not performant enough for tablets. Any ideas?

Comment: You could use the android Canvas framework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602045/java-directed-graph-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally bit the bullet and used a 2d game engine to render the graph. I was not able to find any frameworks that handle hypergraphs on android

Comment: can you tell which engine you are using?